# "Nuget failed to install/uninstall the selected package"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I'm trying to uninstall the entityframework V6 package from my solution. But I keep getting this message :
[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a workaround to safely delete the entityframework?

Comment: Have you tried using the console manager to uninstall the package? `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework` or you force it to unintall `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force`

Answer (score 2):

Try editing the `packages.config` to remove the package reference manually. Then install/uninstall again using GUI for nuget.